# Python unittest: Mock function in TestCase class

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

My approach to mock testing functions looks like this:

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from main import my_function


def my_mock(s):
    if s == 'hello':
        return 'goodbye'
    return my_function(s)


class TestMyFunction(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('my_function', side_effect=MyMock.my_mock)
    def test_my_function(self, mock_get):
        s = 'hello'
        self.assertEqual('goodbye', my_function(s))
```

This works. But if I have multiple tests, where `my_mock_1` patches `test_my_function_1` and `my_mock_2` patches `test_my_function_2` and so on, the mock definitions are very far from the test definitions and the code becomes hard to read.

Is there a way to get the mock definition closer to the tests they belong to?

---

What I tried was

```
class TestMyFunction(TestCase):
    @staticmethod
    def my_mock_1(s):
        ...

    @mock.patch('my_function', side_effect=my_mock_1)
    def test_my_function_1(self, mock_get):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def my_mock_2(s):
        ...

    @mock.patch('my_function', side_effect=my_mock_2)
    def test_my_function_2(self, mock_get):
        ...

    ...
```

But this fails with the exception
`TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not an iterator`.